# Is it possible to parametrize web [URL] query?

Tags: url, parameters, powerquery

I am querying data via web [URL] from smapOne application using access token provided by SmapOne. SmapOne is an application that allows you to create an user-friendly forms to submit data ([www.smapone.com](http://www.smapone.com)). Data from our SmapOne users can be then "downloaded" to Excel and modified by PowerQuery. My problem is that now the database with the entries is getting quite big (lots of datasets) and the querying takes a long time, because during every update of the connection, all data are being downloaded. The connection to SmapOne database is done in Excel via:

Data > New Query > From other sources > From web

There I specify the URL of the particular SmapOne form (database table) together with my access token. My question is then - can I add some parameters to this URL to be able to query just specific data - for example data from last two days? I know the structure of the target database (tables), but I am not familiar with the URL parameters. In correlation with SQL I would use "select" and "where" commands, but I don't know if any possibility like this exists also for querying via URL...

In case there is any possibility, do you know any good source of information, where I can learn more about querying via web? Or do you know any better solution to my problem? Maybe any setting in PowerQuery to download only new entries?

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: I have never used Smap, but they have some API on their website https://platform.smapone.com/backend/swagger/ui/index#/Smaps/Data.

Comment: The equivalent of `SELECT * FROM <some_table> WHERE <some_condition>;` would be to use `Table.SelectRows` (details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-selectrows) and pass a selector function that will be invoked against each row and should return a boolean representing whether that row should be kept. You might also find `Date.IsInPreviousNDays` (details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-isinpreviousndays) useful.

Comment: The filtering will occur locally and not at the API level, meaning the API is potentially still going to be sending you the same amount of data, meaning your queries might potentially still take the same amount of time. If you provide the code you're currently using (with sensitive information removed), it might enable people to make more informed suggestions regarding alternative approaches.